# Mongo 4.2 error out stage requires a string argument, but found object

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

Im running the current Mongo query and getting this error:
{
"message" : "$out stage requires a string argument, but found object",
"operationTime" : "Timestamp(1634539335, 2)",
"ok" : 0,
"code" : 14,
"codeName" : "TypeMismatch",
"$clusterTime" : {
"clusterTime" : "Timestamp(1634539335, 2)",
"signature" : {
"hash" : "sP5j8mWdcjkUzZ3iHkg3obPhjMw=",
"keyId" : "6985187295267651587"
}
},
"name" : "MongoError"
}

I used this code for earlier copy to other s3 bucket and didn't had problem.

Does anyone see what is the problem?

````
var startDate = ISODate("2021-04-10");
var endDate = ISODate("2021-04-11");
var currDate = ISODate()
publishersId.forEach(publisherId =>
{
    for (var d = startDate; d <= endDate; d.setDate(d.getDate() + 1)) {
        print(publisherId + "_" + d);
        db.direct_client_extended_alerts_dl.aggregate([
        {
            "$match":
                { "publisher_id":publisherId,"created_date": d}
        },
        {
            "$out":
            {
            "s3": {
                "bucket": "mongo-datalake-prod",
                 "filename": {
                    "$concat": [
                     "direct_client_extended_alerts/", {"$toString": "$publisher_id"}, "/",
                     {"$toString": "$created_date"}, "/",
                     {"$toString":currDate},"/"
                    ]
                    }
                }
        }
        }
        ],{ allowDiskUse: true })
    }
}```
````

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the problem, I was running the query from my PROD DB and not from my DATALAKE PROD DB. Once I changed it to DATALAKE DB it runs.

Comment: Does that mean db version were different ?

Answer (score 0):

According to the [official documentation](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/out/) of `$out`:

> Starting in MongoDB 4.4, you can specify the output database.

As you said you are using MongoDB 4.2, the feature is not yet supported. You may either consider:

1. upgrading your MongoDB
2. try to use [$merge](https://docs.mongodb.com/v4.2/reference/operator/aggregation/merge/#pipe._S_merge) and see if it helps
3. using other method to export the data.

Comment: As I wrote, I already used it before and it worked!!!

Comment: Is it possible to replicate your working setup(i.e. the one that you can execute the command without issue)? If so, you may want to do a `db.version()` in a mongo shell to check whether there is any discrepancy between the versions of the 2 setups.